# Jupyter dashboard freezes when opening path which contains many files

Tags: jupyter, dashboard

I'm using jupyter dashboard to browse files in remote linux server. But it often become slow or even frozen when opening directory containing many files (maybe thousands). I wonder is my problem common? Is there any extensions to solve this, maybe allowing user to browse by switching pages?

Thank you for answering my question.